# Redirect to non-https pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I have come accross many solutions similar to what I need but I have tried changing them and have had no luck, it seems to be ignoring them sometimes and not other times.

Essentially I have a site which I need to have https on only on certain pages or all php pages if that is easier but not for friendly urls e.g. /womens/skirts/

So far I added at the bottom in the if statement:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!\.php
RewriteRule %{HTTPS} =off
```

Also in case it makes a difference there is some code at the top to generate the friendly urls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /psyche/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^401$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/psyche/(payment|admin|provider|partner)/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$
RewriteRule loader_(.+).css loader.php?type=css&md5_suffix=$1 [L]
RewriteRule loader_(.+).js loader.php?type=js&md5_suffix=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I would really appreciate anyones help as the when you are in HTTPS the friendly urls don't work which I never realised so am getting pressure off my client I don't understand why it isn't working though. Even if not a solution maybe someone could point me in the right direction or tell me where I'm going wrong.

Many Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I don't understand. Why shouldn't the friendly URLs work in HTTPS? They should work normally. Why are you trying to rewrite HTTPS to "off" (which won't work this way anyway)?

Comment: The last paragraph is the key. Friendly URLs shouldn't be affected by whether HTTPS is used or not. Perhaps you should be looking to fix the cause rather than make a work-around for the symptom.

Comment: Good point but it only needs to be secure on the account and payment pages and I thought that when it was under https the pages would load slower as the content has to be encrypted and decrypted. Also keeping https on would be fine but it just throws a 404 when I go to any of the friendly urls under https??

Comment: @Thomas: if you don't need HTTPS, then you're right, HTTP will be quicker. However, if HTTPS is available some users prefer to use it for the whole site (there's even a firefox plugin that attempts to force it - [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere))

Comment: @Spudley: yes thanks, the client doesn't necessarily want it to be none https for speed reasons but obviously it doesn't work at the moment so they just want it to work lol

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS and HTTP sites are configured by seperate .conf files in Apache. Is it possible that the SSL version of the site has .htaccess files disabled? The rewrite could very well be correct, but since Apache's got .htaccess overrides disabled, the SSL version of the site never sees them.